# WCF self hosted gzip content without IIS

Tags: wcf, soap, gzip

I've a self hosted wcf service (basichttpbinding) that communicate with an Android app it's working ok.

Now a new requirement to support gzip compression is added.

I saw some examples and implemented them, but have no luck there:

http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/anton_staykov/archive/2010/08/24/silverlight-wcf-service-compression-azure.aspx

http://www.frenk.com/2009/12/gzip-compression-wcfsilverlight/

When I made a little test turning on the gzip compression in IIS it's working ok, but my scenario must be self hosted service.

Any example with self hosted WCF + SOAP + gzip is available that emulate the same IIS gzip feature?

Many thanks !!